# how to set up env variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I want my `bash` script to set `PYTHONPATH` to the `pwd`.
so

```
EXPORT PYTHONPATH=`pwd` ?
```

How could I accomplish that?

Comment: this might help you out: http://blog.streamitive.com/2011/12/01/export-pythonpathpythonpath/

Comment: It's `export`, not `EXPORT`. Apart from that, what's wrong with the command in the question? (You might use `"$PWD"` rather than `pwd`.) Suppose `$PYTHONPATH` is already set; do you want to ignore the current setting?

Comment: @KeithThompson after I execute, i do $PYTHONPATH  on the cmd line and I don't get anything ... that's what concerns me

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm executing the following command: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:"$PWD"`

Comment: That's not the command in your question. Stack Overflow uses backticks to format code samples, so it's hard to tell exactly what command you're using. Bash lets you use `$(command)` rather than enclosing the command in backticks. If you run the `export` command in a script, it applies only to that script; environment updates are not propagated to the parent process (in this case, to the interactive shell from which you invoked the script).

Comment: @KeithThompson how do I do them to set the `PYTHONPATH` without modifying `.bash_profile`? I only need it once to run a script ...

Comment: If you put the command in the script, it will take affect in the script. It just won't affect `$PYTHONPATH` in your interactive shell. `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:"$PWD"` should work, though it's better to place the quotes differently: `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$PWD"` -- but I'm still not clear on what your problem is. The command in your question is incorrect; is that the *exact* command you're using, or are you using the command in your comment?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
echo 'export PYTHONPATH="/home/user/mydir"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile`
then when I do from the interactive shell `echo $PYTHONPATH` I get nothing ...

Answer (score 0):

According to
[the source](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

if you are using a login shell

```
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

if you are using a non-login shell

```
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`' >> ~/.bashrc
```